# Order a Preg_Match_All Array With Subpatterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Is it possible to sort sub patterns array keys so that Gender comes first, Name comes second, and Age comes third, insead of Name, Age, Gender

Also, is it possible to get ride of the numeric keys and values, and just keep the associate keys and values?

```
Array
(
    [categoryOne] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Dave | 12 | M
                    [Name] => David 
                    [1] => David 
                    [Age] => 12
                    [2] => 12
                    [Gender] => M
                    [3] => M
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lisa | 44 | F
                    [Name] => Lisa 
                    [1] => Lisa 
                    [Age] => 44
                    [2] => 44
                    [Gender] => F
                    [3] => F
                )

        )

    [categoryTwo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Ann | 32 | F
                    [Name] => Ann 
                    [1] => Ann 
                    [Age] => 32
                    [2] => 32
                    [Gender] => F
                    [3] => F
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You have gender listed twice in your desired sort order...

Comment: Iterate over the result list, pick out values, assign to a new array with the desired key order. It's just five lines of codes, nothing difficult. Or did you stumble with something else?

Comment: @mario Thats the only way then....to create a new array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort the arrays by key, with a given function implementing an arbitary sort order.

The numeric keys can be filtered out with a combination of [`array_diff_key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) and [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php); though it's easier to do it with a loop most likely.

Going over the arrays can be done with `array_map()`, twice if the outer "category" level is of arbitrary length.

```
$categoryMatches = array(...);

$categoryMatches = array_map(function($cCategory) {
    return array_map(function($cEntry) {
        $cEntry = array_diff_key($cEntry, array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($cEntry), "is_integer")));
        $fieldSortOrder = array_flip(array('Gender', 'Name', 'Age'));
        uksort($cEntry, function($aKey, $bKey) {
            return ($fieldSortOrder[$aKey] < $fieldSortOrder[$bKey] ? -1 : ($fieldSortOrder[$aKey] > $fieldSortOrder[$bKey] ? 1 : 0));
        });
        return $cEntry;
    }, $cCategory);
}, $categoryMatches);
```

The above is untested, but should give the rough idea.